# Firestore Increment - Cloud Function Invoked Twice

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

With Firestore Increment, what happens if you're using it in a Cloud Function and the [Cloud Function is accidentally invoked twice?](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees)

> To make sure that your function behaves correctly on retried execution attempts, you should **make it idempotent** by implementing it so that an event results in the desired results (and side effects) even if it is delivered multiple times.

E.g. the function is trying to increment a document field by 1

```
document("post/Post_ID_1").
updateData(["likes" : FieldValue.increment(1)])
```

So while Increment may be **atomic** it's not **idempotent**? If we want to make our counters **idempotent** we still need to use a transaction and keep track of who was the last person to like the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will increment once for each invocation of the function.  If that's not acceptable, you will need to write some code to figure out if any subsequent invocations are valid for your case.

There are many strategies to implement this, and it's up to you to choose one that suits your needs. The usual strategy is to use the [event ID in the context object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#eventId) passed to your function to determine if that event has been successfully processed in the past.  Maybe this involves storing that record in another document, in Redis, or somewhere that persists long enough for duplicates to be prevented (an hour should be OK).

Comment: Yep understood. Just want to make it clear (for myself, and others) that these Increment counters don't protect against double invocations.

Comment: Question on the eventID in the context object, would that be the same ID even with multiple cloud function invocations from the same document? E.g. if you have an onCreate function that gets triggered twice on the same object, is the eventID going to be the same (and can use to make things idempotent)?

Comment: Okay, so then eventID is unreliable in the instances of a double invocation of things like "onCreate" trigger of the same document. You should probably use the docID to use for idempotency.

Comment: No, it's reliable in that case.  The event id will be the same for the same change if it happens to be duplicated by the system.  This is true for any type of change: create, update, or delete.  Or, the more generalized write that combines all three.  If you have two different clients both trying to create the same document, and you don't want to allow that situation, you should be using a transaction to defend against that case.